# If query for number sections in Batch

Tags: batch-file

is there a way to make a If query for specifig 
number sections in Batch?

Something Like this:

```
IF "Var1"=="1-10" (

 do something

)
```

the 1-10 should stand for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

I want to make 10 queries (1-10,11-20,21-30, ... , 91-100)

Is that possible?

Comment: If and only if `Var1` always contains a numeric value, you could do: `if %Var1% geq 1 if %Var1% leq 10 ( rem do something )`

Comment: If I do it like that I get a syntax error with the second "IF".

Comment: Probably `Var1` is empty; what is displayed when putting `echo/%Var1%` immediately before that double-`if` line?

Comment: It seems to have a problem with GEQ if I test with "var1"=="1" it works but if i do "var1"GEQ"1" or even EQU it doesnt count the "(" for some reason?

Comment: You need to read the variable, so write `%Var1%` istead of `Var1` (in the latter case you are just comparing the literal string `Var1`)...

Comment: I did that sry, I just forogt them in the comment. Here is what I have for testing.set Var1=1
echo %Var1%
IF "%Var1%"GEQ"0" (
 echo test
 echo test2
)

Comment: it gives me this error "
"(" can not be syntactically processed at this point" but if i use "==" it works.

Comment: What about just copying my code with no missing characters and no extra ones??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@echo off
set Var1=1
for /l %%i in (0,1,10) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 10 or below
for /l %%i in (11,1,20) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 11 - 20
for /l %%i in (21,1,30) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 21 - 30
for /l %%i in (31,1,40) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 31 - 40
for /l %%i in (41,1,50) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 41 - 50
for /l %%i in (51,1,60) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 51 - 60
for /l %%i in (61,1,70) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 61 - 70
for /l %%i in (71,1,80) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 71 - 80
for /l %%i in (81,1,90) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 81 - 90
for /l %%i in (91,1,100) do if %%i==%Var1% echo 91 - 100
```

Here you can change `set Var1=1` to any other number and it will correspond. You can replace `echo N - N` with your commands.

Also, `set Var1=1` can be removed from the above example if used with your code as I simply set it to demonstrate the behaviour. Here is an extract from the help when running `for /?` so you understand the numeric behaviour.

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

    The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
    So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
    generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```